# How to configure DPDK application working as L3 device to filter traffic between external network and LAN

Tags: nat, dpdk

Please suggest ideas to configure NAT for DPDK application working as L3 device to filter traffic between external network and LAN.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions only. Try https://ServerFault.com

Comment: This is dpdk programming query only.

Comment: So, you're not asking about NAT configuration but something else?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author is asking for code solution without even sharing a snippet.

Comment: @Vipin I am not asking for code solution.Just ideas to configure only.

Comment: @ima ohh then I did not understand the question, can you please rephrase the question title and intention and what you tried to guide you?

Comment: This post is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975763/how-can-i-configure-my-ec2-instance-running-dpdk-to-filter-traffic-between-elast?rq=1

Comment: hash table for NATing is one solution. Since its mentioned in dpdk doc it was mentioned that userdefined field in ACl Rulefile can be used for setting NAT rule https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/l3_forward_access_ctrl.html just checking whether some  suggestions can provided to define the rule format for NAT with ACL rule file.